# Build SGX-SDK with LLVM

Tags: linux, llvm, llvm-clang, sgx

I have cloned the source for sgx-sdk from [git](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx) repo. I want to build it with LLVM instead of gcc.

I have tried

> make CC=clang-7 CXX=clang++-7 sdk

but it seems to be running into one problem after the other. 
Eg.

1. There were bunch of CFLAGS options which were not compatible with clang. - I removed them.
2. ````
   dwarf/Gfind_unwind_table.c:59:8: error: implicit declaration of function
     '_Uelf64_valid_object' is invalid in C99. ```
   ````

There were other issues before which I was able to solve by editing concerned files, but I am stuck at this point. GCC does not throw this error but clang does, and I am unable to understand why is this happening. 
If my understanding is correct an implicit declaration error, if exists should be thrown by both GCC and clang.

My build machine is Ubuntu 18.04. I have clang-7 installed and have used it in past in  building other applications like Nginx.

Comment: "it seems to be running into one problem after the other." is not a problem's description with which we can help you. You need to be more details and more specific. See [ask].

Comment: My Bad. Thanks for pointing it out. My concern is if it is even possible to build SGX-DSK using clang. I am updating the question with a few instances of errors while using clang.